# Highlight a Cell/Control in TableLayoutPanel in C# windows application?

Tags: winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am adding controls dynamically, one by one from ListBox on a Button click in TableLayoutPanel in Windows application.

How do I highlight (color change) last added cell / control in the panel? I tried out a lot, but couldn't find any solution for this.

Can any one help on this?